# Use php echo output in GA4 jquery link tracking code

Tags: php, jquery, google-analytics

I'm using the below jQuery code to track link and button clicks on my website, which works absolutely fine:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  'use strict';
      $(".trck_laagstProd_ext_comp").on('click', function(event){
          gtag('event', 'TEST3', {
            'event_category': 'Products_Extern',
            'event_label': event.currentTarget.href });
      });
});
</script>
```

I have a php echo output to display an external domain in text (for example google.com) which I'd like to add to the Google Analytics 4 event. I tried adding it as below but that doesn't seem to work.

It's this piece of code: `<?php echo esc_html($domain); ?>` Which outputs the following on my website:
[Link to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILn3t.png)

So I'm trying to add this piece of code in the jQuery code like below:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  'use strict';
      $(".trck_laagstProd_ext_comp").on('click', function(event){
          gtag('event', 'TEST3', {
            'event_category': 'Products_Extern',
            'event_label': event.currentTarget.href,
            'event_merchant': "<?php echo esc_html($domain); ?>" });
      });
});
</script>
```

So it does send 'event_merchant' to Google Analytics but it sends the actual data as `"<?php echo esc_html($domain); ?>"` and not as the actual output. [Please check out this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/05gDU.png)

I'm not that experienced with jQuery and Google nor SO doesn't seem to solve my question unfortunately.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What is value holding in`<?php echo esc_html($domain); ?>`  ?

Comment: @MaheshThorat It's printing a domain name value from another script. For example Amazon.nl, Amazon.de, Pabo.nl in this screenshot (https://i.imgur.com/KU8oEDz.png). I want to see the external domain name the visitor is going to. I can't do that with event.currentTarget.href because the url is cloaked.

Comment: What do you mean with "it doesn't seem to work"? Does it not send the 'event_merchant' at all? Or is the value not as expected? Unfortunately it's impossible to test your code if we don't know what's in $domain exactly.

Comment: @simplism Sorry for being so vague. I changed the topic to be more clear with image examples. I hope you can help me. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

If you're getting the data/text as `<?php echo esc_html($domain); ?>` and not the output of `<?php echo esc_html($domain); ?>` then you're not executing this script from a .php file (yourfile.php) or it is a .php file but php isn't enabled on the server.